# NETBEANS 7.4: "no tag was defined for name: register" + “No library found for namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/my_composite_component”

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, netbeans, composite-component

I'm using Netbeans 7.4 on Linux Mint 13 Maya. I learn how to write a simple JSF composite component. But I have some errors:

when I try to launch my app:

```
<my_composite_component:register> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/my_composite_component, but no tag was defined for name: register
```

and when I try to use my component:

```
“No library found for namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/my_composite_component”
```

Heres the structure of directories in my Netbeans project:

[image]

and the code:

**register.xhtml - my composite component**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      >

    <composite:interface>

        <composite:attribute name="nameLable" />
        <composite:attribute name="nameValue" />
        <composite:attribute name="emailLable" />
        <composite:attribute name="emailValue" />

        <composite:attribute name="registerButtonText" />
        <composite:attribute name="registerButtonAction" 
                             method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />

    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>

        <h:form>

            <h:message for="textPanel" style="color:red;" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="textPanel">

                #{cc.attrs.nameLable} : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{cc.attrs.nameValue}" />

                #{cc.attrs.emailLable} : 
                <h:inputText id="email" value="#{cc.attrs.emailValue}" />

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.registerButtonAction}" 
                             value="#{cc.attrs.registerButtonText}"
                             />

        </h:form>

    </composite:implementation>

</html>
```

and **index.xhtml** where I try to use my component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:my_composite_component="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/my_composite_component"
      >

    <h:body>

        <h1>Composite Components in JSF 2.0</h1>

    <my_composite_component:register 
        nameLable="Name" 
        nameValue="#{user.name}" 
        emailLable="E-mail" 
        emailValue="#{user.email}"

        registerButtonText="Register" 
        registerButtonAction="#{user.registerAction}"
     />

    </h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using jsf 2.2 and instead of java.sun.com/jsf , i use this as namespace :

```
xmlns:my_composite_component="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/my_composite_component
```